# Making code and output appear incrementally in R presentations

Tags: r, r-markdown

I know it's possible to make [bulleted lists appear incrementally](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/revealjs_presentation_format.html#incremental_bullets).

Is it possible to do the same with a code sample and the output of that code, whether the output is text or a plot?

**EDIT:**

When I run @MartinSchmelzer's code, I get this error:

```
pandoc: Could not fetch https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js
HttpExceptionRequest Request {
  host                 = "ajax.googleapis.com"
  port                 = 443
  secure               = True
  requestHeaders       = []
  path                 = "/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"
  queryString          = ""
  method               = "GET"
  proxy                = Nothing
  rawBody              = False
  redirectCount        = 10
  responseTimeout      = ResponseTimeoutDefault
  requestVersion       = HTTP/1.1
}
 (InternalException (HandshakeFailed Error_EOF))
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 67
Execution halted
```

**EDIT 2**:

The solution proposed here doesn't work. https://github.com/jimhester/knitrBootstrap/issues/172 Adding

```
output:
  html_document:
    self_contained: no
```

to the yaml header allows the document to be knit, but images are no longer knit and it appears to be in notebook format.

Comment: R presentation or Reveal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well in case you are using Reveal presentations you could do the following:

````
---
output:
  revealjs::revealjs_presentation:
    incremental: true
---
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.chunk').children().each(function(i) {
    $(this).addClass('fragment');
  });
});
</script>

## Test

- 1
- 2

<div class="chunk">
```{r}
plot(cars)
```
</div>


## Test 2
<div class="chunk">
```{r}
head(mtcars)
```
</div>
````

First you load the jQuery framework. Then we have a short JS script that finds all div containers with class `chunk`. From those we take all the children (source codes, outputs or plots) and add the class `fragment` to them. This will make them appear incrementally.

Finally wrap a `<div class="chunk">` around all those chunks that should appear that way.

When I put all the JS code above (both script elements) in a file called `js.txt` and use `self_contained: true` as well as `includes: in_header: js.txt` it works fine and also offline.

```
---
output:
  revealjs::revealjs_presentation:
    incremental: true
    self_contained: true
    includes:
      in_header: js.txt
---
```

Comment: This looks really cool, but when I run it I get an error. It's long, so I've added it above.

Comment: Are you on an office computer? Maybe a firewall issue?

Comment: No, I'm on a personal computer at home without any firewalls

Comment: Got it!! I needed to add `self_contained: no` under revealjs

Comment: Yeah that would be an issue. Anyhow you could always save a version of jquery locally and include it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with jquery. How would I do that?

Comment: Made a little update after testing. Gotta sleep now though. Any questions left Ill check them tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks! This works when I knit then view in the browser, but not when I publish to RPubs. Whatevs...

Comment: Im not sure what the problem is. When I publish the version with `in_header` to RPubs, everything works fine!

Comment: I think the issue is with `self_contained: no`. If I set it to true, I get the error above, even if I have js.txt and `in_header`